# How do I @import a Sass file only if it has content in it besides comments?

Tags: html, css, import, sass

I'm studying Sass and I was working on building a reusable Sass template based on the [7-1 pattern](http://sass-guidelin.es/#the-7-1-pattern). The pattern suggests importing all of the separate stylesheets into one main.css file. My main.scss file has a bunch of @import statements that import individual _example-section.scss sections.

The CSS output can be hard to navigate in a debugger, since all of the CSS is in one file, so I wanted to add comments that begin sections of each file, so that _reset.scss contains:

```
/* ------------- */
/* --- Reset --- */
/* ------------- */

...
```

The problem is that some sections/Sass files may not be used (maybe I won't have a sidebar, but I'd like to keep it in the Sass template), which makes the final output have the following empty sets of comments:

```
/* ------------------ */
/* --- Typography --- */
/* ------------------ */
/* -------------- */
/* --- Footer --- */
/* -------------- */
/* ------------- */
/* --- Forms --- */
/* ------------- */
/* --------------- */
/* --- Sidebar --- */
/* --------------- */

...
```

Ideally, I'd like to know if there is a way for Sass to only @import a file if there is content in it other than the comments (so that, for example, if I don't have any footer styles, it won't show the `/* --- Footer --- */` comment).

Comment: You can use scss comments, two forward slashes `//` - it won't export in the CSS.

Comment: You can't.  However, if you're doing this for debugging purposes, you should probably look into using source maps.

Comment: @PaulRedmond The thing is I want to have CSS comments, but only if there are styles that come in the file being imported. `//` completely ignores all comments when exporting to CSS. I want to be able to see the sections when I am in FireBug/FF Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 forward slashes for sass they won't be exported to the CSS:

```
// Bourbon 4.2.3
```

Or normal CSS comments that will:

```
/* Bourbon 4.2.3 */
```

To answer your question: No, but you can enable source maps in the developer tools (E.g. Chrome) to see the source scss of where the style is coming from.

Comment: Note that the OP specifies that they're using the comments as a debugging aid.  That implies to me that they *want* them in the compiled CSS.

Comment: Ah, I see. From what I know, you can have one or the other but not check if there are styles and then export the comments if there is.